# Installing Wordpress on IIS7

Tags: wordpress, iis-7, fastcgi

I am trying to install wordpress on IIS but I cant seem to make it work.

I keep receiving the following error:

Error Summary

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
>
> An unknown FastCGI error occured
>
> Detailed Error Information
>
> Module: FastCgiModule
>
> Notification: ExecuteRequestHandler
>
> Handler: PHP52_via_FastCGI
>
> Error Code: 0x8007010b
>
> Requested URL: http://localhost:80/blog/index.php
>
> Physical Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Blog\index.php
>
> Logon Method: Anonymous
>
> Logon User: Anonymous

I cant seem to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [Microsoft Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx), which will help you set this up in IIS. This requires almost no prior experience in setting up web applications, and should work out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Web PI is definitely the easiest way configure IIS.

Alternatively, you could also try with [XAMPP for Windows](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) if you don't necessarily have to use IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Error code 0x8007010b means 'The directory name is invalid'. First of all check if the folder `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Blog` exists but could also be another folder referenced from your PHP.INI configuration file.